# Python - Prints next 5 days excluding Mondays and Sundays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code that starts from the current day, prints on the screen and inserts in an array the following 5 days excluding Monday and Sunday. Except that in the array and in the print it always comes out the same day. Here is the code.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def findDay(date): 
    day = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday() 
    return (calendar.day_name[day]) 

Today = datetime.date.today()
StartDay = Today.strftime("%d %m %Y")

Days = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
KeyboardDays = ['', '', '', '', '']
DayCount = 0
count = 0

while count <= 4:
    NextDay = Today + datetime.timedelta(days=DayCount)
    Day = str(findDay(StartDay))
    if Day in Days:
        KeyboardDays[count] = Day
        print(KeyboardDays[count])
        count += 1
    DayCount += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is simply because `Day = str(findDay(StartDay))` never changes. And you never use NextDay. so your dayCount increment is of no use. So you rename NextDay to StartDay
or use NextDay instead of StartDay
Try this:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def findDay(date): 
    born = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d %m %Y').weekday() 
    return (calendar.day_name[born]) 

Today = datetime.date.today()
StartDay = Today.strftime("%d %m %Y")

Days = ['Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
KeyboardDays = ['', '', '', '', '']
DayCount = 0
count = 0

while count <= 4:
    #NextDay = (Today + datetime.timedelta(days=DayCount)).strftime("%d %m %Y")
    StartDay = (Today + datetime.timedelta(days=DayCount)).strftime("%d %m %Y")
    Day = str(findDay(StartDay)) # or Day = str(findDay(NextDay))
    
    if Day in Days:
        KeyboardDays[count] = Day
        print(KeyboardDays[count])
        count += 1
    DayCount += 1
```

Comment: `StartDay = Today.strftime("%d %m %Y")` is useless

Comment: @Simone Yes it is.